# One button should be disabled if input is null, but another button is affected as well

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I'm trying to write a login/register page and make the "login" button disabled if the fields are not filled in (login and password). However it's also affection the "register" button, which is asking for the fields to be filled in as well.

I'm not sure what is causing this and removing the "required ng-model" from the labels stops the login button from working with "ng-disabled". Can someone please help me understand what's causing this behavior?

```
<div class = "form-group" aling="center">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail" >&nbsp; Usuário &nbsp;</label>
  <input type='text' placeholder = 'Usuário'
     class="form-control" required ng-model = "user">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleInputPassword">&nbsp; Senha &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
     <input type='password' placeholder = 'Senha'
        class="form-control" required ng-model = "password">
  </div>
  <p>
  <div class="main" ng-controller="loginController">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" 
        ng-disabled="form1.$invalid" ng-click="login(user,password)">
     Login</button>
  </div>
  <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" 
     ng-click="register()">
     Register
  </button>
  <p></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what happening is when you're clicking on `Register` button it tries to submit a form. You should change `type="submit"` of `Register` button to `type="button"`. Also even if you don't specify any `type` on button, it considered as `type="submit"`.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="register()">
     Register
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked as expected with type=button. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @GabrielMisselGonçalves Glad to help you. Go ahead and accept the answer, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You Register button is in the same form as all the other fields and has type `submit` and since the two inputs are `required` the submit button is automatically disabled

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- You define the controller `loginController` only for `Login` button. Hence, `username` and `login` fields are out of scope for this controller.
- Define the controller in the parent element(outside of the form) in the DOM.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("loginController", function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="loginController">
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
<div class = "form-group" aling="center">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail" >&nbsp; Usuário &nbsp;</label>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Usuário'
     class="form-control" required ng-model="user">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleInputPassword">&nbsp; Senha &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
     <input type='password' placeholder='Senha'
        class="form-control" required ng-model="password">
  </div>
  <p>
  <div class="main">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" 
        ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="login(user,password)">
     Login</button>
  </div>
  <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="register()">Register
  </button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```